# Turn function names, its arguments and return type of a class into a function parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference, variadic-tuple-types

I am building a library and trying to turn following implementation of the interface

```js
const testInterfaceImpl = {
    testSN: (a: string, n: number) => { return "" },
    testN: (n: number) => { return },
    test: () => { return 0 }
}
```

into function where I developer is able to interact with `testInterfaceImpl` using `targetFunction`

```js
const [stringResult0] = targetFunction([ ["testSN", "", 6] ])
const [stringResult0, voidResult1, stringResult2] = targetFunction([ ["testSN", "john", 5], ["test"], ["testSN", "doe", 7] ])
const [numberResult0, _] = targetFunction([ ["testN", 5], ["testSN", 999999] ]) // TS should error on ["testSN", 5]
```

In other words, I am aiming to create types for function according to the supplied class/object.

- Function should be able to infer available function names of provided class, and arguments **of provided function** name and its return type as well
- Developer should be able to provide multiple variadic tuples with mentioned above
- Function returns an array of same length as arguments provided with typed results
- *(Edit)* Errors or IntelliSense should be able to provide type of arguments required by selected function(-name)

I have tried following

```js
interface TestInterface {
    testSN: (a: string, n: number) => string
    testN: (n: number) => void
    test: () => number
}

type FNArgTuple<FN extends keyof TestInterface> = [FN, ...Parameters<TestInterface[FN]>]

const testFn = <FN extends keyof TestInterface>(args: FNArgTuple<FN>) => {
    return {} as ReturnType<TestInterface[FN]>
}

const returnsString = testFn(["testSN", "", 6])
const returnsVoid = testFn(["testN", 5])
const returnsNumber = testFn(["test"])

testFn(["testSN", ""])  // error: not assignable to ["testSN", string, number]
testFn(["test", 9])     // error: not assignable to ["test"]
testFn(["testN", ""])   // error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

which works as expected but, of course, only accepts one function at a time.
After many tries, I came up with function that can accept and return multiple functions.

```js
const testInterfaceImpl: TestInterface = {
    testSN: (a: string, n: number) => { return "" },
    testN: (n: number) => { return },
    test: () => { return 0 }
}

const targetFunction = <FN extends keyof typeof testInterfaceImpl>(args: FNArgTuple<FN>[]) => {
    return args.map(([x, ...args]) => {
        return testInterfaceImpl[x](...args) // error here, so I am not bothered about return types
    })
}

targetFunction([["test"]])   
targetFunction([["testSN", "", 6]])
targetFunction([["testSN", "", 6], ["test", "", 6]]) // should TS error on ["test", "", 6] but doesn't
targetFunction([["testN", 5], ["testSN", 5]])        // should TS error on ["testSN", 5] but doesn't  

targetFunction([["testSN", ""], ["testN"]]) // error
targetFunction([["test", 9]])               // error
targetFunction([["testN", ""]])             // error
```

This is oversimplified version of what I am trying to achieve but covers everything that's important. Sharing
[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-V3GxZSmWekKgECDZisZjeWic8lYXDYRT+IhmWhbd0WU0eZyuDxldJvF1uhJygCcStxIbA8gjUZjGDjCaTxGQqb9Gk93uFvvTiTlsvLJlD1dokYgtNAAHJs3gJ6BEBNsNGyfXEPHE8mW2ZxxO8-IJzUpKGoLAECh0L4yPgaD1iOQqDRPkxWBxuLwBAARYQwUCWYRwEQSFaapCtCTIqJovg9LYUKMnoKiCji8T+kkDhOPyeC5t4joZGEkQGDaWqgLKoCVG4+QgShKS7jhWT4RqhGkeRhT2FidHcqAAAMJFskBXzIMcuDnE0FDUHQfygACQKjOMUwzHMW6NPJCSwfcEE9HCAmIqAyIdF0N4AuEmzlrR5H0USZIIrsviKIwdiikMez7Jpxl4eRuJmQwynLHBhBqfgmxDE8dj7LsmkhEO4YjqAqDyIQWappoZK+J4S7+NGMX4rwia0GQ6rsfUjQYORlTKtUNT8R0QkiQ+vptsgnoDqAtQCVV95iaKdUBkRcqKpaFWCcgwltfQHU9l1soeIqHh1X2PVPOWoYYKgOX4Lw4DQGGEagPQabFoGk1PKA-i5aAnC0Oo2ATsgzWVYN1XtZsdWZqAFrTWNz0Wo1FaLctl5rRtw7MNtDCdR9h3HZyZ0XVdpjlS1d3DbV72zU8b0mg14VVpFzA3QNQ2iSNj09qW83BhW5ODljEa461BNI+jgakxT5MRRGQA) with above code.

I see that I have created function where function names and their parameters are mixed from each other but I am not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Making `FNArgTuple` create a union of possible tuples: https://tsplay.dev/w2zXxw

Comment: @Peter do you need return types and proper errors?

Comment: as @caTS answer is best for general usage, but return types and proper errors may need some more tweaking

Comment: @Dimava What's wrong with the errors emitted with my solution? I think they're pretty clear and what OP was asking for. And for the return type, I think that's fine as well. If you have a solution that removes the need for `//@ts-ignore` (I used it there since the workarounds aren't relevant to this problem), then by all means share it.

Comment: @caTS `Type '"testSN"' is not assignable to type '"testN"'.` instead of `[testSN, ...] is not [testSN, ...]`. Nothing much, reaaly, just nagging

Comment: Thank you both. caTS your solution works well, thank you a lot. Though, as Dimava's last comment mentioned it does not return proper error or IntelliSese with argument's (tuple element's) types (I will edit my question to include that requirement). As I am using arrays in this case, I would like user to be presented with at least argument types (as I suppose there is no way to have argument names as well.